# Passing array from PHP to JavaScript NOT WITH JSON

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

My work host has an old version of PHP and it's not supporting json_encode(), so I need another way to pass array of strings from PHP to JavaScript, can't figure out how.... please help.

This is my current working code that's needed "downgrade":

PHP:

```
$arr = array($first_name,$last_name, $phone, $email, $number);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

JAVASCRIPT (ignore the missing brackets):

```
function get_repeat_request_details(request_id){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            var arr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("tb_f_name").value = arr[0];
            document.getElementById("tb_l_name").value = arr[1];
            document.getElementById("tb_phone").value = arr[2];
            document.getElementById("tb_email").value = arr[3];
            document.getElementById("tb_number").value = arr[4];
```

Comment: why downgrade? implement your `json_encode`. It's not that difficult (I bet there are some implementations already)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php there is a custom implementation in the comments that works great

Comment: Just use XML.  It's very standard in the industry.

Comment: possible duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431417/how-do-i-encode-an-array-to-json-without-json-encode)

Comment: Thanks, seems like a duplicate issue, couldn't use that first post's solution though. PHP upgrading or touching on host is not an option sadly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/jsonencode-alternative-php-4

It will detect if `json_encode` already exists, but if not, then provides an alternative.