# Simple PHP array to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array in php lets call it:

```
$nums = array(10,25,52,32,35,23);
```

I want to send it to my javascript function like this:

```
var nums=[10,25,52,32,35,23];
```

How can i do this? 
(My javascript file name is "nums.js")

Edit:

nums.js is a javascript code. It changes the values of table in the html. But the values only exist in php. So i have to send the values to javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **PHP >= 5.2**

The `json_encode` function is for this purpose:

```
<?php echo 'var nums=' . json_encode(array(10,25,52,32,35,23)) . ';'; ?>
```

Docs: http://php.net/json_encode

> **PHP < 5.2**

If you can't use `json_encode`, [take a look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5431513/2812842) for a way to define an equivalent.

Comment: This prints the array into my web page. But dont change the values in my javascript. My code is like this: <?php $nums = array(10,25,52,32,35,23); ?> <script src="nums.js"></script> I want to change the values inside the nums.js file.

Comment: @user3179249 easiest way is add new script tag before external javascript, e.g: `<script> var nums = "<?php echo json_encode(array(10,20)); ?>"; nums = JSON.parse(nums); </script><script src="nums.js"></script>`

Comment: Tried it that way, still my array in nums.js is not overwritten.

Comment: You can't overwrite a variable in a different file like that... You'll need to pass the variable into the script using a function of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use json_encode() but only possible from php 5.2
see more: https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php

or you can use this function:

```
function php2js ($var) {
    if (is_array($var)) {
        $res = "[";
        $array = array();
        foreach ($var as $a_var) {
            $array[] = php2js($a_var);
        }
        return "[" . join(",", $array) . "]";
    }
    elseif (is_bool($var)) {
        return $var ? "true" : "false";
    }
    elseif (is_int($var) || is_integer($var) || is_double($var) || is_float($var)) {
        return $var;
    }
    elseif (is_string($var)) {
        return "\"" . addslashes(stripslashes($var)) . "\"";
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: This FIRST suggestion should be to use `json_encode()`, not to use it as an afterthought.  Even if you don't have native PHP `json_encode()` there are PHP libraries out there to do this for you.  You should not be manually building the JSON representation from the array.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your javascript file is being parsed by PHP before being sent to the client, then this should work:

```
<?php echo "var nums=[" . implode(',', $nums) . "];"; ?>
```

Comment: +1, simple, good ol' PHP. Though I heard using single quotes gives faster page load ;).

Comment: What do you mean by parsed?
I run my javascript at the end of the page like this:
<script src="nums.js"></script>

Comment: @DanielLisik Logically, that's true, but I can't imagine it ever making a noticeable difference.  Still, I actually usually use single quotes for text strings anyway.

Comment: @user3179249 - then you should be fine.  As long as it's included in the same file as your PHP.

Comment: @user3179249 - Nevermind my last comment, I just re-read what you wrote.  I isn't going to work like you want it to, because you're browser will grab nums.js separately and it won't be processed by PHP on the webserver (unless you have some really weird webserver setup...)

Comment: I tried it but it just printed the arrays into the web page.

Comment: NO. Don't build the array representation manually. This is poor coding practice. Use `json_encode()`.  Among other things this will make sure values are properly escaped and data types are properly sent.

Answer (score 0):

Just `json_encode()` the array and then output it as an array literal in javascript.

```
<?php
$nums = array(10,25,52,32,35,23);
$nums_json = json_encode($nums);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var nums = <?php echo $nums_json; ?>;
</script>
```